# Dropping columns with common phrase inside each name, using R

Tags: r

I am using Census Bureau data, which provides estimates and margins of error. It downloaded as an Excel file with the following column names:

```
HC01_EST_VC01
HC01_MOE_VC01
HC02_EST_VC01
HC02_MOE_VC01
HC03_EST_VC01
HC03_MOE_VC01
HC01_EST_VC03
HC01_MOE_VC03
etc.
```

Once I read the table into R (using read.csv), how can I then drop/remove the margin-of-error columns (e.g. `HC01_MOE_VC01, HC02_MOE_VC01`)? I have read about dropping columns with common starting fragments but not common within-name fragments.

I will appreciate suggestions. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

We can use `grep` to subset the columns that are not 'MOE'.  The output of `grepl` is a logical vector.  We get TRUE values corresponding to those substrings that match the pattern `_MOE_` and FALSE for no match.  We negate (`!`) it so that the TRUE becomes FALSE and FALSE as TRUE so that all column names that do not have the `_MOE_` is TRUE.  This can be used to subset the columns.

```
df1[!grepl('_MOE_', names(df1))]
```